# Php SOAP WSDL pass parameters?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to send parameters this WSDL file.

https://integration.gezinomi.com/ErcanOutService.Services.SaleService.svc?wsdl

https://integration.gezinomi.com/ErcanOutService.Services.SaleService.svc?xsd=xsd2

I'm almost finished integration but **HotelReservation** function it turns empty.

I use this function **__getTypes** for **HotelReservation()** result this parameters :

```
[2] => struct Reservation {
 decimal Commission;
 ArrayOfGuest Guests;
 Invoce Invoce;
 boolean IsEbInsuranceWant;
 string RoomGuid;
 string SaleNote;
 decimal TotalPrice;
 ArrayOfint TransferPrice;
}
    [3] => struct ArrayOfGuest {
 Guest Guest;
}
    [4] => struct Guest {
 dateTime Birthday;
 string Email;
 boolean IsChild;
 boolean IsMen;
 string Mobile;
 string Name;
 string Surname;
 string Title;
}
    [5] => struct Invoce {
 string Address;
 int CityId;
 string CompanyName;
 int CountryId;
 int DistrictId;
 string Email;
 boolean IsForeigner;
 boolean IsInvoiceSend;
 string Name;
 string Phone;
 string PhoneCityCode;
 string PhoneCountryCode;
 string SurName;
 string TaxId;
 string TaxOffice;
 string TcId;
}
```

I'm using the standard php soap class and basic authentication:

```
<?php
$result2 = $client2->HotelReservation(
        array('Reservation' =>
            array(
                'Commission' => "",
                'Guests' => array(
                        'Guest' => array(
                        'Birthday' => "",
                        'Email' => "",
                        'IsChild' => "",
                        'IsMen' => "",
                        'Mobile' => "",
                        'Name' => "",
                        'Surname' => "",
                        'Title' => ''
                    )
                 ),
                    'Invoce' => array(
                        'Address' => "",
                        'CityId' => "",
                        'CompanyName' => "",
                        'CountryId' => "",
                        'DistrictId' => "",
                        'Email' => "",
                        'IsForeigner' => 0,
                        'IsInvoiceSend' => 0,
                        'Name' => "",
                        'Phone' => "",
                        'PhoneCityCode' => "",
                        'PhoneCountryCode' => "",
                        'SurName' => "",
                        'TaxId' => "",
                        'TaxOffice' => "",
                        'TcId' => ""
                        ),
                    'IsEbInsuranceWant' => "",
                    'RoomGuid' => "",
                    'TotalPrice' => ""
                )
        ));
```

How do I pass parameteres cant get the result.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm so tired this problem, It's an actual question and problem.